# Django Admin filter for another model inside edit form

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I face the following problem. 
I have 3 different Models: 
1.) Testsuite (which contains a list of Tests) 
2.) Test (which have different groups. e.g. "production","live", "frontend", "backend" , etc) 
3.) Groups (list of all available groups.

The tester needs to create a test suite with a list of tests.
But adding them one by one is not suitable.
The better option is to add them in bulk sorted by groups.

I am looking for 2 solutions.
Include the filter option inside the edit form.

[image]
That filter here would be nice
[image]

or The other options.

The horizontal list in the edit form
is able to search for the Group tags.

Some code to get a better understanding.
in the forms.py:

```
<pre>
class TestSuiteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestSuiteModel
        fields = ('name','testcases' , 'nutzer' )
        widgets = {
            'testcases': autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(
                'Testcase_autocomplete'
            )
        }

class TestCaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestCaseModel
        fields = ('name',  'testsuite' , 'gruppen' , 'portal' )
        widgets = {
            'testsuite': autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(
                'Testsuite_autocomplete'
            ),

            'gruppen': autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(
                'Gruppen_autocomplete'
            ),

        }


class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = GroupModel
        fields = ('name', 'testcases' )
        widgets = {
            'testcases': autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(
                'Testcase_autocomplete'
            )
        }
</pre>
```

the admin.py

```
<pre>

class TestSuiteFormAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('name',)
    form = TestSuiteForm
    list_filter = ['name']

class TestCaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TestCaseForm
    list_filter = ['gruppen', ]
    list_display = ['name', ]
    search_fields = ('name',)


class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = GroupForm
    list_filter = ['name']
</pre>
```

and models.py

```
<pre>

class TestCaseModel(models.Model):
    #id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gruppen =  models.ManyToManyField('GroupModel' , blank=True)
    testsuite = models.ManyToManyField('TestSuiteModel' , blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Testcase"
        verbose_name = 'Testcase'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Testcases'

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class TestSuiteModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    testcases = models.ManyToManyField('TestCaseModel' , blank=True)
    nutzer = models.CharField(max_length=200,  blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "Testsuite"
        verbose_name = 'Testsuite'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Testsuits'

class GroupModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    testcases = models.ManyToManyField('TestCaseModel',  blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was one solution I found. but that does not work with many to many Fields.

```
from pprint import pprint
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

class CategoryListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
title = _('TestCaseModel')
parameter_name = 'testcasemodel'

def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
    categories = TestCaseModel.objects.all()

    for obj in categories:
        pprint(vars(obj))
    #filter_objects = TestCaseModel.objects.filter(Some_attribut = "some_name")
    #filter_objects = TestCaseModel.objects.filter(group = "backend")

def queryset(self, request, queryset):

    if self.value():
        return queryset.filter(testcasemodel__id=self.value())

class TAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):      
    list_filter = (CategoryListFilter,)
```

For many-to-many relations, you get a none value and there you are not able to filter for that.